# Weird thing in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

When I was practice in [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/), I've be trying to match with a regular expression that checks if a word starts with a non-consonant. My approach it's check cases how that begins with a non-letter, or starts with a number or underscore, or checks the empty string
I've founded a strange behaviour:

My regex `/^[aeiou_0-9\W]|^$/i` match the `k` and `s` consonants!. I don't understand why.

Any ideas?

A link to example -> http://rubular.com/r/0zt0VPmcwr

Comment: It is the \W that matches them. I do not know why though.

Comment: Furthermore it only matches, when used with i-Modifier and inside a character glass.

Comment: It is a bug in Ruby regex. See [`[\W]`](https://ideone.com/mIi82W), it matches `k` / `K` and `s` / `S` (yeah, with `/i` only).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew AFAIK, it is the more-or-less common glitch with negated matchers used inside `[]`. `\R` (that is to match anything consisting of `\r` and `\n` since Ruby 2) does not work in `[]` as expected. That is because most negated matchers are built as a combined regexps (unfortunately I can’t find a proof link now.)

Comment: @mudasobwa: Well, I do not think this should be a bug. [`/[^[:alnum:]_]/i`](https://ideone.com/4S0rmt) works anyway. `\W` could be parsed by the regex engine as that construct. Gonzalo, just remove `/i` and add uppercase variants: `/^[aAeEiIoOuU_0-9\W]|^$/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes and no. `\W` is parsed that way, but afterwards it’s _becoming a part of `[]` group_, and the latter brings a problem.

Comment: Well, I mean I think the Ruby regex engine needs fixing since [PCRE/JS/Python engines deal with `/[\W]/i` well](https://regex101.com/r/dD1dR1/1).

Comment: Ah, yes, definitely :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very funny because you have stumbled across a bug specifically for just the letters k and s when using \W with /i (it's like a perfect storm).

Here is the link that explains the bug: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4044

Perhaps this was patched in a later version of ruby, but if you don't feel like going through the hassle of going to a new version of ruby, then you can just explicitly make an inverted character class of all the consonants:

```
/^[^bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]|^$/i
```

Here is the rubular link: http://rubular.com/r/URgsWP3suQ

Edit: 
So, something else I noticed about your regex is that your regex (and the regex I provided above) matches only the first letter of the words where as the regex that I provided matches the whole word. I don't know if this makes a difference for you, but I felt it was worth pointing out. Please see the difference in the highlighting in the rubular link above and the one below (See how the link above only highlights the first letter of the words where as the link below highlights the whole words):

```
^[^bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz].*|^$
```

http://rubular.com/r/IVJ03uOK4h

Comment: `(('a'..'z').to_a - %w(a e o u i)).join` looks more expressive and error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in Ruby regex in some versions. Select version 1.8.7 in the dropdown and you will see your regex works properly.

Edit. Check the docs at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html. More specifically, in the metacharacters section:

- /\W/ - A non-word character ([^a-zA-Z0-9_]). Please take a look at Bug [#4044](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4044) if using /\W/ with the /i modifier.

Comment: This is by no means an answer, it should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I just recently started posting in SO and need 50 rep to comment on the question.

Comment: Then you could try to elaborate, e. g. find a proof links, show the alternative examples for different versions etc. The fact that this “is a bug in some ruby version” is evident for both OP and all readers.

Comment: Thanks, now this answer has it’s added value.

Comment: Thank you for guidance. I will try to be as thorough as possible in my answers from now on.